# Problems with making a bootable USB Drive on a Mac

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, mac, apple, usb-creator

I am following [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) to create a Bootable USB Drive for me Mac and this is the output I get on step 8.

```
new-host:~ Jason$ sudo dd if=/Users/Jason/Desktop/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1s2 bs=1m
dd: /dev/rdisk1s2: Invalid argument
691+1 records in
691+0 records out
724566016 bytes transferred in 164.544659 secs (4403461 bytes/sec)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you unmounted the USB stick with `unmountDisk /dev/rdisk1s2' before running the command to write to the USB? It's very important that this is done before running that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use unetbootin it is SO MUCH EASIER just reformat your disk and then throw the iso onto the flashdrive using unetbootin. http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Dang! I might take a look at that. I made a 12.04 Live-USB for my Macbook 1.2, late 2007. It helped to have a working Live-CD so I could check Linux names for the USB stick, and so on. I used the instructions at ubuntu.com for making a Live-CD, but had to burn the disk 4-5 times before I got one that worked reliably.

I could NOT make a Live-USB following the directions at ubuntu.com. They may work for newer Macbooks, but not mine. I found a link to [these](http://mac.linux.be/content/installation-ubuntu-karmic-koala-macbook-pro-31-usb-stick) instructions. Then I messed around with the `grub.cfg` file for days before I got:

```
# grub.cfg for MB1,2 USB Install F11

# Timeout for menu

timeout=20

default=0

menuentry "UBUNTU USB" {

       echo
       echo "FAKEBIOS"
       fakebios

       echo
       echo "SET ROOT"

       #set prefix=(hd1,2)/boot/grub
       #set root=(hd0,1)

       set root=(hd1,2)

       #set root=(hd1,2)/boot/grub 
       #echo

       #echo "INSMOD"
       #insmod (hd1,2)/boot/grub/linux.mod

       echo
       echo "LINUX"
       linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb2 video=efifb agp=off

       echo
       echo "INITRD"
       initrd /initrd.img

       echo
       echo "IMPLIED BOOT"
}
```

I found the echos very helpful. It gets all the way up to the implied boot and almost finishs, but failed mounting things on root, like /dev on /root/dev. I played around with the 'root=' arg on the linux command until hit on the one that there. I left a bunch of other stuff in comments. They didn't work for me, but they might for you.

I didn't find much out there. I even found a claim the Macbooks can't boot from a USB stick. I hope this helps.