# Create a bootable USB drive for installing Linux

Tags: live-usb, mac

I have a netbook that I would like to start using agan and and need to reinstall things (I think an update broke a bunch and it is faster to rebuild vs figuring it out.  Anyways I have my Macbook Air that I would like to create a bootable usb drive on it to install Linux on my Netbook.

Most of the steps that I've found googling are for installing Ubuntu on a Mac, which is not what I want to do.  I would like to build the bootable key on my Mac to install Linux on my netbook.

Did some searching on this site and a lot of questions linked back to [Problems with making a bootable USB Drive on a Mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160236/problems-with-making-a-bootable-usb-drive-on-a-mac) which is all about creating a bootable USB for installing Linux on Mac.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the bootable usb stick on a mac using [this](http://evan.borgstrom.ca/post/1314205955/osx-bootable-usb-from-iso) utility.

Comment: I was literally about to post this when you did

Comment: Look I understand exactly what Ubuntu is and found the whole "There is no Ubuntu for Mac or Ubuntu for Windows" pretty pointless in this.  Also I understand how to install Ubuntu and didn't need the link on how to install Ubuntu either.
All I was looking for was the help in creating the bootable USB drive.  If you do a simple Google Search for this, 99.9% of the links refer to installing Ubuntu on the Mac on the USB drive you just created.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue with an older Debian netbook.

I found the the [linux forum on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux) to be the best place to get help.  It's the first time people answered helpfully and without the usual air of condescendence I've come to associate with *nix.