# Bootable USB Ubuntu Server

Tags: mac, usb-installation, intel-nuc

I have a MacBook Pro, I just ordered an Intel NUC and build components.  Just want to tinker with Linux.  Can I use my MacBook Pro to create a bootable USB in order to install on the NUC?  I don't want to install on the Mac, only on the NUC.

I did find this similar question a couple of times but neither were answered (**correctly**).

EDIT: Should not have assumed incorrect! But it did not seem clear to me that I could assume to use the bootable USB made created on a Mac for a non-Mac computer.  Thank you for the clarity!

EDIT AGAIN: Clarifying for the downvote?  The Official Tutorial is great, but my question was specific to using the Mac to create the bootable USB for the NUC (non-Mac).  The OT isn't clear, remains Mac centric.  Same with this prior question/answer, I couldn't find that as a qualifying answer for me.  Super appreciate everyone's help!
[Create a bootable USB on a Mac to install Ubuntu on a PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364683/create-a-bootable-usb-on-a-mac-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-pc?rq=1)

Nor:
[Create a bootable USB drive for installing Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278700/create-a-bootable-usb-drive-for-installing-linux?rq=1)

Comment: Official Tutorials (at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials) are created and maintained by community members at https://discourse.ubuntu.com . You can suggest improvements, or even offer an entire tutorial of your own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem installing Ubuntu on Several computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308352/problem-installing-ubuntu-on-several-computers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use my MacBook Pro to create a bootable USB in order to install on the NUC?

Yes, you definitely can.

The [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview) is complete and easy to follow.

However, I can also recommend the fool-proof DD based [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) tool. Make sure MacOS is selected so it downloads the usual .dmg installation file. Instructions of use are so simple as:

1. **Select Image** - the ISO file downloaded from ubuntu.com
2. **Select drive** - here you'll be selecting the target drive
3. **Flash!** - "burns" the image into the USB stick. Please wait as it may take a long time.

Comment: I understand how to create the USB bootable on a Mac.  But will the USB bootable made on the Mac work as a USB bootable for the NUC?  I don't want to create it for use on the Mac, which the tutorial does not clarify.

Comment: Yes, it will work. There's no "Mac specific" images or methods. Apple hardware is Intel based since a long time ago.

Comment: @DMC415 As usual, if this answer was helpful, you should accept it. PS - I didn't downvoted your question but I totally understand why other users did it (explained in the comment below the question).

Comment: Thanks, the additional clarity is appreciated.  I think it might be easy enough to see why I needed the extra hand holding.  i can take criticism, especially given that I'm getting the answer!  Hopefully this question/string will help the next person like me.

Comment: Just a follow up, ChanganAuto was 100% correct.  Not "Mac specific", installed perfectly.  Now on to my next dilemma....